# improve 2D array in C++

Tags: c++

This is may code for 2D array. I will using it for Battleship game.
I want to ask, if its necessary to use a dynamic memory because I have two 2D array. Also I want to ask if anyone can tell my how to improve or fix my code

I'm not sure that I used the Class correct, but its my first time

enter code here

```
#include <iostream>
#include<array>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Board {

public:

int grid[15][15];





int initBoard(int A, int B) 
{   

int grid[A][B];
for(int col=0; col<A; col++) //Outer column loop
{
    for(int row=0; row<B; row++) //Inner row loop
    {
        grid[col][row]=0;
    }
}
}

void printBoard(int A, int B)  
{

    if (B == 10){
        cout<<endl;
     cout<<"       ---{WELCOME TO THE BATTLESHIP}---\n"<<endl;
 cout << "    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (B == 15){
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"                ---{WELCOME TO THE BATTLESHIP}---\n"<<endl;
        cout << "    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| 13| 14|" << endl << endl;

    }
for(int i=0; i<A; i++)  //column loop
{

    for(int j=0; j<B; j++)  //row loop
    {
        if(j==0)
        {
                        if(i<=9){
                                cout << i << "   " ; //print row number and spaces before new row
                        }
                        else if(i>=10){
                                cout << i << "  " ;
                        }

                    }

                    grid[i][j]=0;
        cout << grid[i][j] ;
        if(j <= B)
        {
            cout << " | ";
        }

    }
cout << endl; //new line at end of column
}
cout << endl;
}



}:
int main(){



system("clear");
cout<<endl;
cout<<"***------GAME MENU------***"<<endl<<endl;
int b;
string name;
string surname;
cout<<"    Choose Difficulty\n\n"<<"        1 for Easy\n"<<"        2 for 
Hard\n"<<endl;
cout<<"***---------------------***"<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Enter your name: ";
cin>>name;
cout<<"Enter your surname: ";
cin>>surname;
cout<<"Enter your choice -->";
cin>>b;
   system("clear");

if (b==1){

    Board easy;
easy.initBoard(10,10);
easy.printBoard(10,10);
  cout<<endl;
 }

else if(b==2){
  Board hard;
hard.initBoard(15,15);
hard.printBoard(15,15);
  cout<<endl;
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int grid[A][B];` is wrong for multiple reasons. 1. In c++ array size must be a compile time constant. 2. You are creating a new local variable grid that has no relation to your class member with the same name so whatever you do with the local variable is lost after `initBoard()` finishes.

Comment: `#include <vector>, #include<array>` you are not using any

Comment: okay how to fix that.

Comment: To fix your code, we need to know what problem you are are having.  An [MCVE] is probably required.

Comment: enter comment here

Answer (score 1):

> if its necessary to use a dynamic memory because I have two 2D array.

On my system, Ubuntu 17.10, each thread stack size is 8 MB (default).  You need to figure out your per thread auto-var size, and if your grid is smaller, and enough size is left for max depth function calls, you will not need to use dynamic memory.

Generally, I would not resist using dynamic memory.

> Because I have 2D array

The dimensionality has no impact.  The grid (made with std::array) takes a fixed number of bytes, and the elements are back to back.